# How to go to another page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I would like to refresh the "PrincipalView" every time I choose a new project. The PrincipalView has a menu that is the one who has to send the order.

[Here you can see the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIMVU.png)

[PrincipalView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYQbH.png)

MenuView

```
class MenuView extends StatelessWidget {
  late Usuario usuario;
  UsuarioService usuarioService = UsuarioServiceFirebase();
  MenuView({
    required this.usuario,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
```

[MenuBuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx8IB.png)

```
  List<Column> crearProyectos(context) {
    
    print(usuario.toJson().toString());
    List<Column> lista = [];
    print(usuario.proyectos!.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < usuario.proyectos!.length; i++) {
      Proyecto p = usuario.proyectos![i];
      lista.add(Column(
        children: [
          DrawerListTile(
            title: usuario.proyectos![i].name,
            press: () {
              usuario.idProyectoActual="$i";
              usuarioService.updateUser(id: usuario.id, u: usuario);
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => this));
            
            },
          )
        ],
        
      ));
    }
    return lista;
  }
}
```

I already try:

`Navigator.pushReplacement( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (BuildContext context) => this));`
`Navigator.pop(context);  // pop current page Navigator.pushNamed(context, "PrincipalView");`
`Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  PrincipalView(usuario: usuario)), );`

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUPNt.png)

Comment: refresh `PrincipleView` or go to `PrincipleView` ?

Comment: How can I refresh PrincipaView? I tried to push to PrincipalView but it gives me an error

Comment: please post the error.

Comment: I have already uploaded the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem, I added the method that created the drawables dynamically to the build and in onPress I called Navigation.push.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("MenuView ${usuario.toJson().toString()}");
    List<Column> lista = [];
    print(usuario.proyectos!.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < usuario.proyectos!.length; i++) {
      Proyecto p = usuario.proyectos![i];
      print("CREAR PROYECTOS $i ${p.toJson().toString()}");
      lista.add(Column(
        children: [
          DrawerListTile(
              title: usuario.proyectos![i].name,
              press: () {
                usuario.idProyectoActual = "$i";
                MenuController m = MenuController();
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  // Pass ViewModel down to EditScreen
                  
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return MaterialApp(
                    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                    title: 'iOrganize',
                    theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
                      scaffoldBackgroundColor: secondBgColor,
                      textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme)
                          .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
                      canvasColor: fisrtBgColor,
                    ),
                    home: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                      value: m,
                      child: PrincipalView(usuario: usuario),
                    ));
              }));
              })
        ],
      ));
    }
    return Drawer("All the code)};
```

Comment: Great you fixed it. You may mark your answer as accepted.